# Thread's run does not see its array size increase

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I am currently working on a Java homework. I am asked to create a basic DNS server.
There is an UDPSender class which is a thread listening on port 53.
There is also another thread which is called UDPManager.

UDPManager starts a thread with a nested runnable class which holds an ArrayList of DatagramPacket. The UDPSender aggregates the UDPManager and whenever it receives an UDP packet, it sends it to the manager for him to add it to the arrayList.

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class UDPManager {
private UDPManagerRunnable manager;

public UDPManager(String hostsFile, String remoteDNS, boolean localResolution) {
    manager = new UDPManagerRunnable(hostsFile, remoteDNS, localResolution);
    new Thread(manager).start();
}

public void managePacket(DatagramPacket p) {
    manager.managePacket(p);
}

public void close() {
    manager.close();
}

private class UDPManagerRunnable implements Runnable {
    private ArrayList<DatagramPacket> packets;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> clients;
    private boolean localResolution;
    private boolean running;
    private String hostsFile;
    private String remoteDNS;

    public UDPManagerRunnable(String hostsFile, String remoteDNS, boolean localResolution) {
        packets = new ArrayList<DatagramPacket>();
        clients = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        this.localResolution = localResolution;
        this.running = true;
        this.hostsFile = hostsFile;
        this.remoteDNS = remoteDNS;
    }

    public void managePacket(DatagramPacket p) {
        packets.add(p);
        System.out.println("Received packet. "+packets.size());
    }

    public void close() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        DatagramPacket currentPacket = null;
        while(running) {
            if(!packets.isEmpty()) {
                currentPacket = packets.remove(0);
                byte[] data = currentPacket.getData();
                int anCountValue = data[Constant.ANCOUNT_BYTE_INDEX];
                if(anCountValue == Constant.ANCOUNT_REQUEST)
                    this.processRequest(currentPacket);
                else if(anCountValue == Constant.ANCOUNT_ONE_ANSWER)
                    this.processResponse(currentPacket);

            }
        }

    }

    private void processRequest(DatagramPacket packet) {
        System.out.println("it's a request!");
    }

    private void processResponse(DatagramPacket packet) {
        System.out.println("it's a response!");
    }

}
```

}

This is the UDPManager. The packets are transmitted to the manager correctly as the System.out.println correctly displays "Received packet." and the size of the array does increase. The problem I'm running into is that inside the "run()" it never see the size increasing. The weird thing is that it works perfectly fine in debug.
Any idea why it's acting this way?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Which array should be increased, and where?

Comment: "packets", inside the UDPManagerRunnable. Elements are added to it inside the managePacket method.

Comment: Well, you don't call the method anywhere, to begin with.

Comment: this is a classic producer consumer problem. you should be using a `BlockingQueue`

Comment: I am sorry it is the first time I am asking for help on a forum. I reckon I haven't been very clear. There is another thread calling the method on UDPManager and it's working fine. The problem is just that inside the run it doesn't seem to have look at the same array for some reason as it always sees the array as empty.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know the name of the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok, so other thread puts the data in and your if(!packets.isEmpty()) ` always returns false, isn't it? In that case your code looks ok, but I would add a sleep (maybe 100ms) to your `while (running)` loop to avoid consuming all of the CPU of a core (otherwise the thread will be running endlessly).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your first thread is putting the new data into the **packets** variable, but for the second thread this is not visible. You should synchronize the access to the array.

When you start a second thread all variables are copied. The second thread is only working on the copies. You need to synchronize access to this variables, so changes are made visible to the other threads.

Comment: -1 That's not the problem. It would be a problem if the list reference were being changed, but it isn't. Copies are only made of the references, not the whole object, and the reference never changes - there's only ever one List object.

Answer (score 0):

you should synchronize packets when you access or modify it